# Emacs term-mode colors

Tags: colors, emacs

I used have my term-term-name set to vt1000 and my bashrc set to xterm this worked fine except that colored output did not work.

Then i set the term-term-name to screen and my .basrc to screen that make the coloring work but if i type a message thats longer than the line it does not move to the next line but goes to the beginning of the same line.

Which emulation should i use to make both lines and color work? This is happening on OS X when on linux(debian) it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your term to `xterm-color`.  Mine is set to `urxvt` because that is the terminal emulator I use. When I wasn't using that, I had it set to `xterm-color` and did not have the behaviour you described.